# SharePoint 2007/2010 deployment methods

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer, wsp

I've been developping for SharePoint 2007/2010 for a couple years now.  And I realize at this point that no company are using the same deployment method for new sites.  I'm wondering what are the "Best Practices" to deploy.

Here is the method I've used :

---

**1 - Avoid using WSP method**

- Create the site in **DEV** using the SharePoint GUI Interface (create SubSites, Lists, Libraries, Pages, etc.).
- Customize some minor things through SharePointDesigner.
- When it's done, we package **DEV** using **stsadm -export** and then port it to **QA** and **PROD** using **stsadm -import**.
- When we need to make modification to an existing site, we create a Console app **(.exe)** that makes the necessary modifications, test it on **QA** then run it on **PROD** (and logs every operations in a separate txt file).
- We only use WSP to deploy Webparts, EventReceivers or things that would be used on different sites.

---

**2 - Do everything in WSP method**

- Every time we have a new site to create, we use a provisionning WSP that creates all the content (create SubSites, Lists, Libraries, Pages, etc.) through code.
- We deploy by creating a new empty SiteCollection then install the provisionning WSP and activate it to create everything.
- When we need to make a modification to the site, we modify the WSP so it checks if things exists in code and modify what needs to change accordingly.

---

I personnaly (strongly) prefer method #1 because I believe its simpler and faster.  But I'd like to know some other opinions, what are the best practices in these situations?  I've used method #1 for years and it worked really well actually.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to repost your question on [sharepoint.stackexhange.com](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/). But first check the next list of related questions:

- [What are Sharepoint(MOSS 2007) Developement/Deployment best
  practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967882/what-are-sharepointmoss-2007-developement-deployment-best-practices)
- [What's the downside of using backup and restore site collection as
  deployment methods in #SharePoint2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23809/whats-the-downside-of-using-backup-and-restore-site-collection-as-deployment-me)
- [Sharepoint solution deployment](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27386/sharepoint-solution-deployment)
- [SharePoint 2010 package site collection for deployment to
  production](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5856/sharepoint-2010-package-site-collection-for-deployment-to-production)
- [Best practices for updating production site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10650/best-practices-for-updating-production-site)